# How to properly build unordered list in Angular using ngFor

Tags: angular

In my Angular 7 app, I have the following component, which retrieves a JSON array:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-indices-get',
  templateUrl: './indices-get.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./indices-get.component.css']
})
export class IndicesGetComponent implements OnInit {

  indices: any[];

  constructor(private is: IndexService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.listAllIndices();
  }

   listAllIndices = function() {
     console.log('indices-get.component.ts');
     this.is
       .getIndex()
       .subscribe((data: Index) => {
         this.indices = data;
       });
  };

}
```

When executed, the 'this.indices' is assigned the following:

```
[ {        docs.count: “0”,     docs.deleted: “0”,     health: "yellow”,     index: "userindex2”,     pri: “1”,     pri.store.size: "283b”,     rep: “1”,     status: "open”,     store.size: "283b”,     uuid: "oSjIstqAQN21DNIgl9VjjQ”,     __proto__: Object
    },
    {      docs.count: “0”,     docs.deleted: “0”,     health: "yellow”,     index: "userindex1”,     pri: “1”,     pri.store.size: "283b”,     rep: “1”,     status: "open”,     store.size: "283b”,     uuid: "HhtHVp6vS1S4R4E-b5PKzQ"
} ]
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<h2>Indices</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of indices"></li>
  <span >{{item.index}}</span> {{item.index}}
</ul>
```

When this runs, all I get in the browser is a list of two empty bullets.

What should I change in order to display the content of item.index?

Comment: Can you share Stackblitz/demo of your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your span is outside of the `*ngFor`, making it unable to access the item.

Try

```
<h2>Indices</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of indices">
     <span>{{item.index}}</span> {{item.index}}
  </li>
</ul>
```